# What model should I use to predict a time series like this?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, scikit-learn, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

[image]

This series is calculated from the difference of two day's stock index. I rescaled it using sklearn's StarndardScaler.

It seems LSTM does not work well on this series.

Comment: This mostly looks like white noise. IS there any structure at all?

Comment: @DemetriPananos This is simply calculated from the difference of two day's s&p500 index. However, LSTM works well on the original s&p500 index but not on this.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Actually, that's not what white noise looks like. This chart shows the typical volatility clustering associated with GARCH-type models. Of course this probably does not really help you for point forecasts, but nevertheless.

Comment: @ChrisHaug is it possible to use machine learning models on this series?

Comment: What do you mean by "use"? The main issue is 1) stock returns have little forecastable content in general because of the way such information would quickly feed back into the price itself, and 2) the point of view that investment is a game of who can produce the most accurate point forecasts is very reductive and does not consider the fact that no one is near accurate enough that you can ignore the risks involved. So, if by "use" you mean "is it possible to use ML models to make money with point forecasts based on the history of prices only", the answer is "no, probably not".

Comment: @ChrisHaug I am not trying to make money. I'm just doing a school project. By using LSTM on the difference series data, the training and validation losses seem to be unchanged during the training. The LSTM model seems to work well on the regression task on the original sp500 index data, but as you said, the result might be deceptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be answering this as someone who has spent a LOT of time in the last few years working on financial time series prediction. However, I am not a professional (I do it on my own time etc.)

Generally, you want to go in increasing order of complexity in your models (if this isn't intuitive, I'll be happy to explain why).

So, have you tried an AR, ARMA or ARIMA model? If not, I would recommend by starting with those. There are packages that will do it quickly and easily. I'll tell you now, though - chances are, it will not yield accurate results. But seriously, give it a good try first.

Once you've tried the basic, auto-regressive time series models like I listed above, move on to more complex things, like LTSM. However, I would personally advise against using LTSM for a few reasons:

1. LTSM has a huge number of parameters to train, and if you're working with stock data (especially daily frequency), you don't have more than a few tens of thousands of data points at best. That may seem like a lot, but take a look at how many parameters your LTSM is trying to optimize. Unless your network is very small, the number will be rather high compared to the number of data points you have. If you insist on trying LTSM, I would recommend trying to find higher frequency data.
2. LTSM takes a long time to train (inconvenient)

Like Demetri noted in a comment, that differenced series looks a lot like white noise, which it probably nearly is (most financial time series are damn near white noise). For this reason, I would be genuinely extremely surprised and impressed if you found an accurate model by just feeding in price data like it seems you currently are. Financial data is extremely noisy, there generally just isn't enough signal for your model to pick up on. Of course, maybe I'm just a bit jaded.

So, here's what I would do:

1. Go back to basics, try ARIMA-style autoregressive model.
2. Try ARCH/GARCH model, which is better adapted for time-series with heteroskedastic (not evenly distributed) volatility like your see in your time series (sometimes lots of volatility, sometimes little).
3. Try LTSM (smaller network)
4. If you have found a useful/predictive model in steps 1-3, that's extremely impressive and to me, surprising. If not, then you need to start doing some serious feature engineering. If you're unfamiliar with the concept, do some googling. Essentially, there is almost certainly not enough signal in the raw (financial) time series data for any model to pick up on. You will need to create variables from the raw data in order to better highlight different aspects of the data (think technical indicators) that a model (linear regression, logistic regression, randomforest etc.) might be able to pick up on.

Bonus tip: I have personally found that it's MUCH easier to find strategies by linear regression and by "eyeballing" a bunch of charts before writing a program that can execute based on  a pattern you visually noticed, rather than by ML models. There is just an insane amount of challenge to consider when working with ML in the financial data.

Final note: You commented to Demetri that the LTSM works well on the original time series. I would ***HIGHLY*** recommend you take a much closer look. I can almost promise that the LTSM isn't working well on the original, but that it's doing what most auto-regressive models do when there's no signal to be found - they say for every prediction that the next value will be equal to the previous. When this happens, it will APPEAR as if the model is doing well. You'll plot the predictions vs. actual and it'll look really close, the R^2 will be great but in reality, there's no predictive value - it's just replicating past values because it can't do any better. Perhaps I'm cynical/jaded, but I can almost promise you that's what you have going on with the LTSM on raw price data. As mentioned - using ML for price prediction is extraordinarily challenging.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am only familiar with machine learning and I am currently doing a project in school, so I am afraid to not have enough time to learn AR, ARMA or ARIMA models.

I found one layer LSTM can already reach a relatively good result on s&p500 prediction, which baffles me a lot.

Comment: Ah I see. Well, if you give me more details about your level of experience, project etc. I could give better advice but basically, I'm sorry to say, but this really isn't something that can be done quickly/easily (unless the point of the project is to demonstrate how hard it is). Like I said in the end, PLEASE take a closer look at your original LTSM predictions. They will not be real predictions, just repeating past values. To have any chance of predictive value, you'll need to engineer features (and I'd recommend trying other ML algorithms instead of LTSM for the reasons I mentioned).

Comment: I found one layer LSTM can already reach a relatively good result on s&p500 prediction, which baffles me a lot. For example. this link https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/21713/stock-price-data-manipulation-for-lstm

Comment: Are you doing it as a classification or regression task? How good are the results? Can you provide any link/screenshot to it?

Comment: I plan to do it as a regression task. If you take a look at https://github.com/stefan-jansen/machine-learning-for-trading/blob/main/19_recurrent_neural_nets/01_univariate_time_series_regression.ipynb, the RMSE is around 20.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just took a look. I can only say it so many ways - zoom in on your out-of-sample predictions. You will find that your "predictions" are always lagging behind the real values by 1 period. I know the results APPEAR amazing, but in statistics, and ESPECIALLY in finance, you will never find such good results. Take a closer look at it. The model is just outputting past values as predictions and visually, it looks good but it's not. If it was so straightforward, you and your group would already be multi-millionaires with hedge fund quants begging to know your secret.

Comment: @user900476 Compare the out-of-sample performance of your approach to simply using today's value of the S&P as your prediction for tomorrow. You will find that your model is actually doing almost nothing and providing no value. This is typical of the approach when applied to this domain.